# Android - get a reference to a BroadcastReceiver defined in Manifest

Tags: android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

Is there any way how to get a reference for a BroadcastReceiver defined in Manifest.xml from code?

In my case, we are using a BroadcastReceiver that needs to be included in the Manifest.xml. However it has functionality I would like to reuse from within our code. So instead of creating another similar BroadcastReceiver and instantiating it from the code I would like to obtain a reference to the existing one.

**Additional information:**

My goal is to subscribe to an event on my BroadcastReceiver from my activity - an event that I would like to reuse - instead of creating another instance of this receiver in my activity I would like to obtain a reference to the existing one.

Comment: A Receiver class registered in the manifest has no continuously existing instance. A new instance is created every time it needs to process a broadcast. If you want to use the same class in your `Activity`, just create your own `new` instance, and register it dynamically.

Comment: @MikeM. could you please post this as an answer, exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When registering a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest, you're registering the class, not an instance of it. Each time a broadcast occurs that your `<receiver>` needs handle, a new instance is created to do so, so you can't really get a reference to one as you're describing.

It's perfectly fine to dynamically instantiate and register an instance of a Receiver class that you've also statically registered in the manifest. I would note, though, that if the statically registered class is going to be run anyway - that is, if it's going to handle the same broadcasts as the dynamically registered one - you might consider just notifying your `Activity` from the Receiver class - e.g., with `LocalBroadcastManager`, another event bus implementation, etc. - instead of essentially duplicating Receivers.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to 'obtain a reference' to `BroadcastReceiver` which is already registered.

Just send `Intent` which can be handled by that `BroadcastReceiver` to trigger its action from any point of the code where you have a `Context`.

```
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

If you want to call 'pure logic' without calling `BroadcastReceiver` you have to extract logic from it to some POJO class and call that class directly omitting `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       private SomeAction action;

       public LocationReceiver(){
           action = new SomeAction();
       }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            action.execute();
        }
    };
```

`BroadcastReceiver` can simply call `execute()` but it doesn't know anything about how it works. 
You can reuse `SomeAction` anywhere in your code without having a knowledge about `BroadcastReceiver` at all.

Try to avoid putting a logic inside Android classes.

It's better to have logic in POJO Java classes because it helps to keep [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principle alive and makes testing easier.

Comment: thank you but i don't think that i understood my issue, i probably didn't give enough details. I edited my post so it's a little bit more clear. I have no problem with sending a broadcast / executing some action.

Comment: If you extract `SomeAction` outside `BroadcastReceiver` you will be able to subscribe to `SomeAction` instead a receiver. Even more you will be able to write unit test to it :)

Comment: I see what you mean. Yeah, sounds like a solution. I meant more like putting public event Action OnMyAction; into my BR, obtaining a reference to my BR and then subscribing to that event.